# Django and Buildout Deployment Problem

Tags: django, deployment, mod-wsgi, buildout, recipe

I am trying to deploy my existing django project via buildout, following loosely the instructions [here](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/).

my buildout.cfg file is:

```
[buildout]
parts       =     django python
develop     =     .
eggs        =     myproject

[django]
recipe      =     djangorecipe
version     =     1.2.3
project     =     myproject
projectegg  =     myproject
settings    =     settings
wsgi        =     true
eggs        =     ${buildout:eggs}

[python]
recipe      =     zc.recipe.egg
interpreter =     python
eggs        =     ${buildout:eggs}
```

There are two problems:

1. First of all, if i invoke the python interpreter via ./bin/python, i get an import error with import myproject
2. Secondly if i try to load the django.wsgi file, i also get an apache error

```
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=5045): Target WSGI script '/usr/src/django/myproject/bin/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=5045): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/usr/src/django/myproject/bin/django.wsgi' ignored.
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1]   File "/usr/src/django/myproject/bin/django.wsgi", line 20, in 
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1]     application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('myproject.settings', logfile='')
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1]   File "/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/djangorecipe-0.20-py2.6.egg/djangorecipe/wsgi.py", line 15, in main
[Sun Oct 03 11:57:37 2010] [error] [client ::1]     sys.exit(1)
```

My django.wsgi file is (updated as per suggested changes):

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/usr/src/django/myproject/src',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/djangorecipe-0.20-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.1-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/parts/django',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r85190-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/parts/django',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/src(/usr/src/django/myproject)',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject',
  ]

import djangorecipe.wsgi

application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('myproject.settings', logfile='')
```

my bin/django file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/src',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/djangorecipe-0.20-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.1-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/parts/django',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r85190-py2.6.egg',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/parts/django',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject/src(/usr/src/django/myproject)',
    '/usr/src/django/myproject',
    ]


import djangorecipe.manage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    djangorecipe.manage.main('myproject.settings')
```

Neither the import or the apache server seem to be working

Comment: also, maybe someone with a higher score could make a djangorecipe tag

Comment: There is already a `recipe` tag -- just add that as well as `django` -- no need for `djangorecipe`.

Comment: djangorecipe.wsgi.main() is for command line script, not for use in WSGI script file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Wdym?  `djangorecipe.wsgi.main` has '`wsgi`' in its name, so how come it's not meant to be used with WSGI?  Also, I just used it in my `.wsgi` file and it worked just fine.

Comment: In one case it is being called to return a WGSI application object. In the other to apparently run the main loop of some server. You can't have both.

Answer (score 4):

your problem is that you are setting wrong your egg dependancies in your recipe

in the buildout part the line

```
eggs = myproject
```

you are setting your own myproject django project as a dependancy

in this settings, you need to set all the python eggs (packages) that are dependencies for your django project

for example

```
eggs =
    psycopg2
    south
    django-debug-toolbar
    django-extensions
```

if your project are using postgresql psycopg2 connector, south for database migrations and django-debug-toolbar and django-extensions

you can except from this list any package that you have in your python system install.

remove your project from the **eggs** setting, this one confuse your buildout.

Comment: but according to http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/ i thought that if i dont set my project in the buildout eggs section, then i cant make it available to the other parts... or better said from that link "We want the egg we’re developing to be available to any scripts that run inside this environment, so we set eggs = django-shorturls to get the egg we’re developing installed.".  Am i missing something here?

Comment: yes, django-ulrs is a django app, not a django project, Jacob configure django-shorturls like an developer egg in their deploy to be compliant with the setuptools/buildout scheme. In your case you need to set the extra-path setting and add your project here.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to set extra path to your project so it would be put on python path. Could you paste your django.wsgi and django files ?

Try this config:

```
[buildout]
parts       =     django python
develop     =     .
eggs        =     myproject
extra_paths = 
    src(path_to your_project_source)
    ${buildout:directory}

[django]
recipe      =     djangorecipe
version     =     1.2.3
project     =     myproject
projectegg  =     myproject
settings    =     settings
wsgi        =     true
eggs        =     ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra_paths}

[python]
recipe      =     zc.recipe.egg
interpreter =     python
eggs        =     ${buildout:eggs}
extra-paths = ${buildout:extra_paths}
```

You can also make sure that django.wsgi has executable rights

```
chmod +x django.wsgi
```

Comment: when i do the extra paths = src... line i get some wierd paths in the django and django.wsgi scripts , like '/usr/src/django/myproject/src(/usr/src/django/myproject)'.  See also Reinout's answer.  Is that line correct?  I dont quite understand the function of that setting.

Comment: this line ``src(path_to your_project_source)`` was only example it should somethink like: src or "."

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that looks really strange: `'/usr/src/django/myproject/src(/usr/src/django/myproject)'` in both your bin/django and bin/django.wsgi file.

I've never seen that () stuff.  It looks like it might break things.

Best bet: just run

```
$> bin/python
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

and see what python itself thinks its path is. Buildout sets it up OK, but you've got something I've never seen before in your script.

Another alternative: are you sure your actual code doesn't include import errors that are ending up as import errors of your application (this can sometimes happen if you depend on c-level libraries like PIL or cx_oracle).

Comment: dosent 1.2.3 indicate the django version, not the djangorecpie version?

Comment: Oopsie, you're right, I was asleep.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: i think the () stuff was from the extra_paths = src(path_to your_project_source) bit, a command i dont really understand the purpose of... what should i be looking for in the print sys.path?  my code dosent have any import errors if i use the normal pythong interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just not touching the buildout itself at all, and simply making sure all the eggs were in `PYTHONPATH` when the `.wsgi` script is executed. The `.wsgi` script itself looked like the following:

```py
import os
import sys

PREFIX = '/path/to/my/app'  # the buildout is here

BUILDOUT_EGGS = [
    'Django-1.3-py2.6.egg',
    'South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg',
    'django_haystack-1.2.7-py2.6.egg',
    'djangopypi-0.4.4-py2.6.egg',
    'docutils-0.9.1-py2.6.egg',
    'setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg',
    'zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.6.egg',
    'Whoosh-2.4.1-py2.6.egg',
    'django_registration-0.8_alpha_1-py2.6.egg',
    'djangorecipe-1.2.1-py2.6.egg',
#    'pkginfo-0.9-py2.6.egg',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#    'zc.buildout-1.6.0-py2.6.egg',                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

]

sys.path[0:0] = [PREFIX] + ['%s/eggs/%s' % (PREFIX, egg) for egg in BUILDOUT_EGGS]

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import djangorecipe.wsgi
application = djangorecipe.wsgi.main('myapp.settings', logfile='myapp.log')
```